# How to display the content of a page in a div in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display the text from the image below into a div created by me

http://i62.tinypic.com/2chp8iv.jpg

For each page I want to have different content

For example, on the "About US" to have a text,to the page "contact" alt text and so on...

```
<div id="content_page">
    //some functions
</div>
```

What php  function should I use to show what I want?

I hope I managed to make me understand ... if you need further clarification, please tell

Comment: You can insert divs into your post by switching from "visual" to "text" mode and inserting the HTML that way

Comment: look what it looks like my site if I public .masthead-fixed .site-main

Comment: avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp

Comment: I need a separate div to fix it as they wish

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is a [TinyMCE Custom Style](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles).  This means you can add a button to the editor you'll click to insert custom `<div>`s and such.  It requires editing JS and CSS, no PHP as far as I know ([here's a tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-custom-styles-in-wordpress-tinymce-editor--wp-24980) on the subject), but there's also [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-and-tinymce-advanced-professsional-formats-and-styles/) you might find useful.

Comment: For example, when I click on a lawyer ... to open a div above the footer as in this picture but its contents can be changed from admin panel

Comment: www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp

Comment: You could use Custom Styles to put those contents in a div with a specific id, then use Javascript to move those contents into the sliding content area on pageload.

Comment: <div id="mytext">TEXT FOR MY DIV</div>   #mytext{color:red;}...and doesn`t work

Comment: That's both HTML and CSS code, are you putting it in multiple files or straight into the text editor?

Comment: ok ... it works to change the text color ... but how that text where I want to sit down?

Comment: Looks at "despre noi"...So I want to open page Lawyers